# Probability of an event using basic probability and counting rules.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

**18 chairs are in a row to be occupied by 12 students and 6 professors.
What is the probability that each professor is between 2 students?**

This is one exercise that I don't know how to plot and think of.
Can anyone help? I always struggle with problems like this one.

Comment: You require a bit of combinatorics to achieve the number of possible arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

If we need every professor to be between two students, then we cannot have a professor on the end.

If we denote $P$ for professor and $S$ for student, valid arrangements would have the following form, where blanks represent room for additional students:

$$S\_PS\_PS\_PS\_PS\_PS\_PS\_$$

So far we have used up all our professors and $7$ of our students. We can arrange the remaining $5$ students in the blanks however we wish. Note that a blank can contain one student, more than one student or contain none at all; we are still left with a valid arrangement of students and professors. So we need to find the number of ways to fill in the blanks with students under these conditions. This becomes a [Stars and Bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem with $5$ students and $7$ blanks.

Solving this, we get $$\binom{5+7-1}{5} = 462$$

The total number of arrangements is $\binom{18}{6} = 18564$. With each arrangement equally likely, we get the final probability to be $462/18564 \approx 0.0249$, or about $2.49\%$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but the original question is to have each P between 2S. How would you solve it?

Comment: Please specify the question. Do you mean each professor needs to have at least $2$ students directly on their left and $2$ students directly on their right then? In this case, the answer would be $0$ as it isn't possible with $6$ professors and $12$ students.

Comment: Yes. Each professor should be between exactly 2 students: SSPSSPSSPSSPSSPSS.